# How to set Variadic CRTP base classes to be friend's of the derived class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, friend, crtp, policy-based-design

Main parts of the problem is using **CRTP** with a **policy based design** and **variadic template**. From the policy can't reach the protected or private members from the main/derived class. Because of using variadic template I can't declare policies just as friends.

The question is, how can I set all of the policy classes as friends of derived class.

Given this CRTP solution, what is support multiple inheritance levels and solved the diamond problems without virtual inheritance.

```c++
// Derived     - We would like to obtain access to this type of instance
// BaseDerived - Helper type to avoid the diamond problem without virtual inheritance
template<typename Derived, template<typename> class BaseDerived>
class Crtp {
protected:
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Derived & underlying() noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<Derived &>(*this);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Derived const & underlying() const noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<Derived const &>(*this);
    }
};

// Helper struct to achive multiple inheritance
struct NoDerivedClassTag;

template<template<typename> class Derived, typename Substitute, template<typename> class Base>
using DerivedCrtpBase = Base<std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<Substitute, NoDerivedClassTag>, Derived<NoDerivedClassTag>, Substitute>>;

template<template<typename> class Interface, typename Object>
using is_crtp_interface_of = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same_v<Interface<NoDerivedClassTag>, Object> || std::is_base_of_v<Interface<typename Object::exact_type>, Object>>;
```

Using this CRTP solution in a policy based design with variadic template like this

```c++
template<template<typename> class... Functionality>
class FinalDerived
    : public Functionality<FinalDerived<Functionality...>>...
{
public:
    constexpr int get() const
    {
        return protected_variable_;
    }

// Remove to check the problem
//protected:
    int protected_variable_ {-1};
};
```

The goal is to use the protected variable from the policy like this

```c++
template<typename Derived>
struct Increment
    : Crtp<Derived, Increment>
{
    void increment(int an_value)
    {
        this->underlying().protected_variable_ += an_value;
    }
};

template<typename Derived>
struct Decrement
    : Crtp<Derived, Decrement>
{
    void decrement(int an_value)
    {
        this->underlying().protected_variable_ -= an_value;
    }
};
```

Example of the usage

```c++
constexpr int number {7};

int main(void){
    FinalDerived<Increment, Decrement> derived;

    std::cout << "start: " << derived.get() << "\n";

    derived.increment(number);
    std::cout << "incremented: " << derived.get() << "\n";

    derived.decrement(number);
    std::cout << "decremented: " << derived.get() << "\n";
}
```

[Runnable example](https://paiza.io/projects/YBH1pLaIGdSjQhE_V71XZA?language=cpp)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510844/is-there-a-way-to-specify-all-classes-in-a-variadic-parameter-pack-to-be-friend

Comment: No variadic friend supported currently.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I can think of is to use trait classes, inherited by classes you create and defined *before* your CRTP base and policies, so they would be complete classes. Trait class may contain a pointer or reference to the member you need to reach, the type declarations shared by classes with those traits, etc., see how it's done in  standard components

Comment: Can you provide a small example how is solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As **Evg** wrote it, has an old question with a correct answer.

```c++
#ifndef CRTP_VARIADIC_FRIEND

// M - Macro
// N - Number
// P - Packed parameters
// T - Type
#    define CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_2(M, N, P, T) M(N, P, T) M(N + 1, P, T)
#    define CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_4(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_2(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_2(M, N + 2, P, T)
#    define CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_8(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_4(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_4(M, N + 4, P, T)
#    define CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_16(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_8(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_8(M, N + 8, P, T)
#    define CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_32(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_16(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_16(M, N + 16, P, T)
#    define CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_64(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_32(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_32(M, N + 32, P, T)
#    define CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_128(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_64(M, N, P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_64(M, N + 64, P, T)

#    define CRTP_FRIEND(N, P, T) \
        friend std::tuple_element_t<std::min(static_cast<std::size_t>(N + 1), sizeof...(P)), std::tuple<void, T...>>;

#    define CRTP_VARIADIC_FRIEND(P, T) CRTP_FRIEND_REPEAT_128(CRTP_FRIEND, 0, P, T)

#endif
```

I will try the Trait class solution. It will be an other answer later.

[Runnable example](https://paiza.io/projects/co-QALnYnfrEX9TdC4A_sg?language=cpp)